# How to convert value of numbers to string in php?

Tags: php

How do I convert numbers into a string in `php`?

```
$numbers = [0019,1124];
$result = "'" . implode ( "', '", $numbers ) . "'";
echo $result;
```

Comment: Are the values in the array numbers or strings?  Are you aware that the number `19` has no leading zeroes?

Answer (score 0):

Use `array_map` and `str_pad` like this:

```php
$a = array_map(function($n) {
  return str_pad($n, 4, "00", STR_PAD_LEFT); ;
}, $numbers);
implode(',', $a)
```

Answer (score 0):

In fact your array has an error:

`0019` is an invalid numerical literal and any attempt to convert it into a string will result in simply "1". You should store numerical values:

For example:

```
$numbers = [19, 1124];
```

Then:

```
$result = "'" . implode ( "', '", $numbers ) . "'";
```

will result in:
'19', '1124'

If you want to have them always padded to 4 places you need to store the values as strings:

```
$numbers = ['0019', '1124'];
```

or even better do a mapping:

```
$numbers = [19, 1124];
$newarray = array_map(function($n) {
  return str_pad($n, 4, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT); 
}, $numbers);

$result = "'" . implode ( "', '", $newarray ) . "'";
```